# ARGB Hex color not working in css html

Tags: html, css, background-color, argb

Why is this ARGB hex not working?

```
<td style="background-color: #FFFF9980">
```

Comment: first it's RGBA not ARGB & in HEX there are 6 digits but in your question there are 8

Comment: Hex encoded RGBA/ARGB have 8 digits, I'm not sure what you are trying to say... And ARGB is just as valid of a bit packing for color encoding, though admittedly less common (and not natively supported in HTML/CSS stack). But to the point of the op: do you mean the rgb color `ffff99` with an alpha of `80` or an rgb of `ff9980` and and alpha of `ff`? The bit packing is vital to figuring out what bytes are what, and what color that value represents. You can't just change the encoding and expect to get valid output.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Use `rgba(255,153,128,1.0)` instead of your hex value (though if that really is ARGB it's the same as `#ff9980` in `RGB` - if you meant RGBA then you'll need `rgba(255,255,153,0.5)`).

Comment: @sandeep I did read the question. And before you edited it it said `ARGB`.

Comment: @sandeep The question was asked, I answered a minute later, then you edited the question 3 minutes after that. OP needed a semi-transparent `background-color` as evidenced by the sentence `I really need this color`. I gave him a solution to that problem.

Comment: i just changed ARGB into RGBA. I am not changing the question

Comment: @sandeep Actually, when you change `ARGB` to `RGBA` you *are* changing the question as they are totally different things. The solution when someone wants to add transparency to their colours is to use `rgba(r,g,b,a)`. When someone asks `Why is this not working?` they very often mean `How can I make this work?`.

Answer (score 10):

the [CSS3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#rgba-color) says:

> Unlike RGB values, there is no hexadecimal notation for an RGBA value.

so you will have to use the `rgba(255,153,128,1.0)` mentioned above.

Comment: CSS Color model 4, editor's draft dated 07oct2013, defines an 8-digit hex notation for RGBA: #RRGGBBAA. See http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-color/#hex-notation .

Comment: @EdBurnette To be fair this answer was given a year before that draft.

Answer (score -1):

## ARGB Hex color

RGBA color values are an extension of RGB color values with an alpha channel - which specifies the opacity for a color.

An RGBA color value is specified with: rgba(red, green, blue, alpha). The alpha parameter is a number between 0.0 (fully transparent) and 1.0 (fully opaque).

```
<td style="background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);">
```

```css
#p1 {background-color:rgba(255,0,0,0.3);}
#p2 {background-color:rgba(0,255,0,0.3);}
#p3 {background-color:rgba(0,0,255,0.3);}
#p4 {background-color:rgba(192,192,192,0.3);}
#p5 {background-color:rgba(255,255,0,0.3);}
#p6 {background-color:rgba(255,0,255,0.3);}
```

```html
<h1>Define Colors With RGBA Values</h1>

<p id="p1">Red</p>
<p id="p2">Green</p>
<p id="p3">Blue</p>
<p id="p4">Grey</p>
<p id="p5">Yellow</p>
<p id="p6">Cerise</p>
```