# Is there a color code for transparent in HTML?

Tags: html, css

I'm building a new website, and I'm looking for a transparent navigation bar so the background is visible.

Comment: Yes, there is for certain browsers (new feature). Please, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/60876347/2457251

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11184117/transparent-css-background-color

Answer (score 84, accepted):

There is not a Transparent color code, but there is an Opacity styling. Check out the documentation about it over at [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity)

You will probably want to set the color of the element and then apply the opacity to it.

```
.transparent-style{

    background-color: #ffffff;
    opacity: .4;

}
```

You can use some online transparancy generatory which will also give you browser specific stylings. e.g. take a look at http://www.css-opacity.pascal-seven.de/

**Note though** that when you set the transparency of an element, any child element becomes transparent also. So you really need to overlay any other elements.

You may also want to try using an RGBA colour using the Alpha (A) setting to change the opacity. e.g.

```
.transparent-style{
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .4);
}
```

Using RGBA over `opacity` means that your child elements are not transparent.

Comment: I'm building my website with Tumblr, where do i have to paste the code you've just gave me?

Comment: I do not know the Tumblr set up. You need to put this in the stylesheet, and identify the id or class that matches the navigation bar.

Comment: Technically, the "transparent" color keyword is a shortcut for rgba(0,0,0,0), a fully transparent black, vgl. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#transparent

Answer (score 41):

When you have a 6 digit color code e.g. #ffffff, replace it with #ffffff00.  Just add 2 zeros at the end to make the color transparent.

Here is an article describing the new standard in more depth: https://css-tricks.com/8-digit-hex-codes/

Comment: You need to specify which browser/version can use this. ARGB is not in the CSS3 spec (http://stackoverflow.com/a/12742729) so this is non-standard behavior, and I don't recommend it in any case.

Comment: The [recently adopted CSS standard for hex with alpha is #RRGGBBAA](https://css-tricks.com/8-digit-hex-codes/) so that'd be #ffffff00. It just got added to the standard and [adopted by browsers](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5685348285808640) in mid-2017. So it's not really recommended, at least not yet, as [it's not currently supported in IE/Edge/Opera](https://caniuse.com/#search=hex).

Comment: The correct is add in the start #XXFFFFFF when XX: 00 is 0%, 88 50% FF 100%

Answer (score 27):

All you need is this:

```
#ffffff00
```

Here the `ffffff` is the color and `00` is the transparency

Also, if you want 50% transparent color, then sure you can do...
`#ffffff80`

Where `80` is the hexadecimal equivalent of `50%`.
Since the scale is 0-255 in RGB Colors, the half would be `255/2 = 128`, which when converted to hex becomes `80`

And since in transparent we want 0 opacity, we write `00`

Comment: For 50% you'd actually need to use `#FFFFFF7F`, since you're dealing with hex values.

Comment: 50% is 80 for two digits in hex.  https://css-tricks.com/8-digit-hex-codes/

Comment: Hey, this color gives me blue!!!

Comment: `#ffffff00` gives me yellow (`#FFFF00`) with `mpv` for subs background.

Comment: @cipricus make sure there are 6 F's. And not 4. Because #FFFF00 is indeed yellow.

For transparent white, go for #FFFFFF7F

But it won't work in software like Adobe Photoshop etc.

Comment: I've got it in the end. Thanks. https://gist.github.com/lopspower/03fb1cc0ac9f32ef38f4#all-hex-value-from-100-to-0-alpha

Answer (score 20):

`#0000ffff` - that is the code that you need for transparent. I just did it and it worked.

Answer (score 17):

You can specify value to background-color using rgba(), as:

```
.style{
        background-color: rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.5);
}
```

0.5 is the transparency value

0.5 is more like semi-transparent, changing the value from 0.5 to 0 gave me true transparency.

Answer (score 12):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#transparent_keyword) there is a `transparent` keyword, which is short for `rgba(0,0,0,0)`.

```css
{background-color: transparent;}
```

Comment: While this is correct, please explain a bit more about the answer instead of just pasting code.

Answer (score 7):

If you are looking for android apps, you can use

```
#00000000
```

Comment: Please read the question & tags. It's clearly an HTML, CSS question.

Answer (score 4):

Yeah I think the best way to transparent the background colour (make opacity only for the background) is using

```
.style{
        background-color: rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.5);
}
```

Above statement 0.5 is the opacity value.

It only apply the opacity changes to the background colour (not all elements')

The "opacity" attribute in the CSS will transparent all the elements in the block.

Answer (score 1):

Here, instead of making navigation bar transparent, remove any color attributes from the navigation bar to make the background visible.

Strangely, I came across this thinking that I needed a transparent color, but all I needed is to remove the color attributes.

```
.some-class{
    background-color: #fafafa; 
}
```

to

```
.some-class{
}
```